# get height from ajax request in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How can i get the height of an ajaxreponse in prototype. I need to get the height of the element returned from Ajax.

```
new Ajax.Updater('myDiv','myUrl' {
            parameters: '?something=something',
             onSuccess: function(transport){
            //get height from first div returned        

            }
        });
```

Comment: from my understanding you can't get the height of an element if it's not inside the DOM, so you need to insert it and then test it's height

Comment: Height is dependent on the document the snippet will be embedded in, according to global CSS rules.

Comment: My initial answer missed out the fact that `onSuccess` is called *before* the elements are added (and used `success` rather than `onSuccess`; been doing too much jQuery work lately!); I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to insert the element into the DOM, then measure it. Your best bet is to insert it where it's really going to be when you're done with it (which you're doing, since you're using `Ajax.Updater`). [If for some reason you want to measure it first, you can do that by appending it with the style `position: absolute` and giving it a large negative `left` value (e.g., `left: -10000px`) to keep it off-page, then measure it, then move it to where you want it (removing the big `left`, etc.), but beware of the size changing because of styles and other factors related to its position in the DOM.]

Prototype calls all the usual Ajax callbacks, but note that `onSuccess` is called *before* the update is performed. To get a callback *afterward*, either use `onComplete` (but note it gets called for failures, too) or use `setTimeout` from within `onSuccess`.

Given your code and the comment "get height from first div returned," using `onComplete` would look like this:

```
onComplete: function() {
    var firstDiv, height;
    firstDiv = $("myDiv").down("div");
    if (firstDiv) {
        height = firstDiv.getHeight();
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ozumox)

If you prefer the `onSuccess` + `setTimeout` approach (but note there will be a longer delay between when the element is added and when you measure it):

```
onSuccess: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var firstDiv, height;
        firstDiv = $("myDiv").down("div");
        if (firstDiv) {
            height = firstDiv.getHeight();
            // ...
        }
    }, 0); // Won't really be 0ms, but not much longer
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ozumox/2)

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout` I prefer [`Function#defer`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/defer/). It works the same internally but looks a little neater.

Comment: @clockworkgeek: Ah, yes, I forgot this was using Prototype. :-) I like it too.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply guys. As you said i had to insert the element into DOM to get height.